# Finding the equation of a shpere with given intersections on the XY axes

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

Can someone guide me for finding the equation of a sphere that passes through $M=(-1,2,4)$ and intersects the $OXY$ axis on the circle $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=4$

Sorry for the bad terms in English .

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I consumed that the center of the sphere has coordinates (1,2,Zc)  and then I putted it in the equation with the M and I figured that Zc=4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You have find that the center of the sphere has coordinates $C=(1,2, z_C)$.

With a bit more effort you can find that the radius of the sfere is $R^2=4+z_C^2$.

Now use the given point in the equation $(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2+(z-z_C)^2=R^2$.

Comment: As a result I got Zc=2 am I right? And thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's correct ! Don't forget to accept if you like :)